# Firebase User Porperties quotas

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

There are up to 25 unique User Properties per app in Firebase, and they cannot be renamed or deleted. 
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489
Are there are any quotas on how many different values can be stored in 1 User Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no limit to the number of values that can be stored per property.